# How to call SaveChanges on entities involved in 1-to-many relationship?

Tags: entity-framework

here are my entities

```
public class Article
{
    public Article()
    {
       Associations = new List<Association>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public List<association> Associations { get; set; }
}

public class Association
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public int KeywordId { get; set; }
    public bool IsSubject { get; set; }

    public Article Article { get; set; }
    public Keyword Keyword { get; set; }
}

public class Keyword 
{
    public Keyword()
    {
        Associations = new List<Association>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Association> Associations { get; set; }
}
```

In this situation, I already know `KeywordId` but I don't know yet the `ArticleId`. I'd like to know it's possible to save both entities and call SaveChanges just once.

## EDIT

This is what is coming from the user

```
public class ArticleViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int KeywordId { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you ask this because you want to create a new article with a known keyword. You can set `KeywordId` and `Article`:

```
var article = new Article
              {
                  Title = viewModel.Title,
                  Body  = viewModel.Body
              };
var association = new Association
                  {
                      Article = article,
                      KeywordId = viewModel.KeywordId
                      // other properties
                  };

db.Associations.Add(association);
db.SaveChanges();
```

EF will save the `Article` first and use the generated `Id` for the insert statement of the `Association`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `public int ContentId { get; set; }` or `public int KeywordId { get; set; }` and it is possible to save everything that was changed, if you pull all of those objects from the db and assign props to them that are changed within the same using statement (the correct way of doing it) or attach the object (the common but more dangerous way of doing it)